# Issue with nested functions, inheritance and multithreading in python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I'm trying to automatically take data from several websites. I defined a class

```
class Site1Scraper:
    def __init__(self): ...
    def f1(self): ...
    def f2(self): ...
    def All_f(self):
        self.f1()
        self.f2()
```

Everything about `Site1Scraper` works perfectly and has been tested. I'm now trying to define another class `MultiThread_Site1Scraper` that inherits from Site1Scraper and that starts a thread each time that a method is called and that waits for the previous thread call to finish before doing what it has been called to do. My `MultiThread_Site1Scraper` is:

```
class MultiThread_Site1Scraper(Site1Scraper):
    pT = None
    def __init__(self):
        Site1Scraper.__init__(self)
    def f1(self):
        try:
            self.pT.join()
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            self.pT = Thread(target=Site1Scraper.f1, args=(self))
            self.pT.start()
    def f2(self): 
        try:
            self.pT.join()
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            #print(f"{self.p} \t {self.p.is_alive()} \t")
            self.pT = Thread(target=Site1Scraper.f2, args=(self))
            self.pT.start()
    def All_f(self):
        try:
            self.pT.join()
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            self.pT = Thread(target=Site1Scraper.All_f, args=(self))
            self.pT.start()
```

And my testing program is

```
def MultiThread_Site1Scraper_Test():
    mt_b = MultiThread_Site1Scraper()
    mt_b.All_f()
    mt_b.f2()
```

I tried uncommenting the line `print(f"{self.p} \t {self.p.is_alive()} \n")` and I get: `<Thread(Thread-2 (f1), initial)>    False`
I would expect that when the `f2` method gets called, it sees that `All_f` is still ongoing and waits for it to end, but it doesn't. My final goal is to have the MultiThread_Site1Scraper manage by itself the whole multithreading without having to check whether something is still ongoing inside the main program. Any help is deeply appreciated!
P.S. Can I also multithread the `__init__` in a similar way?

Comment: Re, "...trying to define another class...that inherits from `Site1Scraper`..." Why not define another class that _uses_ a `Site1Scraper` instead of inheriting from it? You probably can make it work either way, but if you get into the habit of _composing_ classes instead of building inheritance trees, you'll make your life easier in the future. The relationship, A _has_ a B, has as much expressive power as, and is more versatile than, A _is_ a B.

Comment: This whole, `join()...start()` pattern looks suspicious. The whole point of using threads is for the program to be able to do different activities _concurrently_ with each other, but the way you're using the `join()`s leaves little room for concurrency.

Comment: @SolomonSlow the kind of concurrency that I'm trying to achieve is between the main program and the Site1Scraper. I want my program to do its computation meanwhile it should use a different thread and periodically look at site1 for new information. In the main program I want to call mt_b.f2() and I want the main thread to go on while a separate thread is doing f2(). Say that f1, which I called previously, is interacting with site1, then the thread is occupied and f2 should wait until f1 has finished. I would like all of this to happen inside the class instead of the main program.

Comment: @SolomonSlow You are likely right about not using inheritance. I will look at it, but the main problem is the whole multithreading thing.